# Should I use update or bulk update?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, updates, bulkupdate

Hi I am trying to update two data point in my table using the sequelize with raw sql as follows:

```
await db.sequelize.query(`UPDATE Person SET status=:status WHERE loginName IN(:loginName)`, {
  replacements: {
    status: 'inactive',
    loginName: ['name1', 'name2']
  },
  type: sequelize.QueryTypes.BULKUPDATE
});
```

Should I use `sequelize.QueryTypes.BULKUPDATE` or just `sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE`? I am not familiar to which one to use since I am just updating two rows here with the WHERE condition, not a bunch of data.

EDIT: The answer that not only gives solution but explains the reason/ concept behind will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

A Sequelize raw query returns an array containing `[results, metadata]`. Since you're performing an `UPDATE` query and it appears you don't need the results, setting `options.type` is unnecessary.

According to the sequelize [docs](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#instance-method-query) the query type "affects how results are formatted before they are passed back" and "`Sequelize.QueryTypes` is provided as convenience shortcuts."

Answer (score 0):

according to https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/raw-queries/,

```
const [results, metadata] = await sequelize.query("UPDATE users SET y = 42 WHERE x = 12");
```

"// Results will be an empty array and metadata will contain the number of affected rows."

When querying in postgres:

```
const response = await sequelize.query(<UPDATE_QUERY>, {type: QueryTypes.RAW});
```

I am getting back a response of type [results, metadata] where the metadata received is of type:

```
Result {
    command: 'UPDATE',
    rowCount: 7,
    oid: null,
    rows: [],
    fields: [],
    _parsers: undefined,
    _types: TypeOverrides { _types: [Object], text: {}, binary: {} },
    RowCtor: null,
    rowAsArray: false,
    _prebuiltEmptyResultObject: null
  }
```

When testing with BULKUPDATE and UPDATE:

- BULKUPDATE

```
const response = await qi.sequelize.query(<YOUR_SQL_QUERY>, {type: QueryTypes.BULKUPDATE});
```

`response` will be a `number`.

- UPDATE

```
const response = await qi.sequelize.query(<YOUR_SQL_QUERY>, {type: QueryTypes.UPDATE});
```

`response` will be of type: `[results, number]`.

The SQL update query executed is the same in both cases. You can test that by adding: `logging: console.log` to the options.

My conclusion is:
Use `sequelize.QueryTypes.BULKUPDATE` if you **don't want** to get back the updated rows.
Use `sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE` if you **want** to get back the updated rows.